# How do you properly integrate unit tests for file parsing with pytest?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pytest

I'm trying to test file parsing with pytest. I have a directory tree that looks something like this for my project:

```
project
    project/
        cool_code.py
    setup.py
    setup.cfg
    test/
        test_read_files.py
        test_files/
            data_file1.txt
            data_file2.txt
```

My setup.py file looks something like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name           = 'project',
    description    = 'The coolest project ever!',
    setup_requires = ['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require  = ['pytest'],
    )
```

My setup.cfg file looks something like this:

```
[aliases]
test=pytest
```

I've written several unit tests with pytest to verify that files are properly read. They work fine when I run pytest from within the "*test*" directory. However, if I execute any of the following from my project directory, the tests fail because they cannot find data files in test_files:

```
>> py.test
>> python setup.py pytest
```

The test seems to be sensitive to the directory from which pytest is executed.

How can I get pytest unit tests to discover the files in "data_files" for parsing when I call it from either the test directory or the project root directory?

Comment: it depends on how you wrote your setup.py so can you please post contents of your setup.py.

Comment: The question was updated with a the setup.py file setup that I'm using.

Comment: updated the answer, does it work?

Comment: The answer works by changing the relative path in the tests such that they are relative to the program root directory, however... the tests now cannot be executed from the "test" folder. I tried doing that without changing setup.py and the tests execute from ">> python setup.py test" That said, I think that the tests should be able to execute from the "test" directory as well. When writing tests, it seems silly to hop in and out of the test directory to run them. I think that there should be a way to make them work from both locations.

Comment: I added a project to github to play around with: https://github.com/flash3780/coolprogram

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution is to define a `rootdir` fixture with the path to the test directory, and reference all data files relative to this. This can be done by creating a `test/conftest.py` (if not already created) with some code like this:

```
import os
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def rootdir():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Then use `os.path.join` in your tests to get absolute paths to test files:

```
import os

def test_read_favorite_color(rootdir):
    test_file = os.path.join(rootdir, 'test_files/favorite_color.csv')
    data = read_favorite_color(test_file)
    # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to try multiple paths to find the files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from coolprogram import *
import os


def test_file_locations():
    """Possible locations where test data could be found."""

    return(['./test_files',
            './tests/test_files',
            ])


def find_file(filename):
    """ Searches for a data file to use in tests """

    for location in test_file_locations():
        filepath = os.path.join(location, filename)
        if os.path.exists(filepath):
            return(filepath)
    raise IOError('Could not find test file.')


def test_read_favorite_color():
    """ Test that favorite color is read properly """

    filename = 'favorite_color.csv'
    test_file = find_file(filename)

    data = read_favorite_color(test_file)
    assert(data['first_name'][1] == 'King')
    assert(data['last_name'][1] == 'Arthur')
    assert(data['correct_answers'][1] == 2)
    assert(data['cross_bridge'][1] == True)
    assert(data['favorite_color'][1] == 'green')
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to pass a dictionary of command name and custom command class to `cmdclass` argument of `setup` function.

Another way is like [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-runner), posted it here for quick reference.

pytest-runner will install itself on every invocation of setup.py. In some cases, this causes delays for invocations of setup.py that will never invoke pytest-runner. To help avoid this contingency, consider requiring pytest-runner only when pytest is invoked:

```
pytest = {'pytest', 'test', 'ptr'}.intersection(sys.argv)

pytest_runner = ['pytest-runner'] if needs_pytest else []

# ...

setup(
    #...
    setup_requires=[
        #... (other setup requirements)
    ] + pytest_runner,
)
```

Make sure all the data you read in your test module is relative to the location of setup.py directory.

In OP's case data file path would be `test/test_files/data_file1.txt`,
I made a project with same structure and read the `data_file1.txt` with some text in it and it works for me.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm not sure I understand how that fixes the problem though. Can you elaborate about why that will allow tests to see files in a subdirectory?

Comment: oh i realized i might have misunderstood the question, you meant data files are not visible to pytest?

Comment: Yes, the tests take a filename which resides in test_files and tests whether my parsing function returns expected values. My test isn't able to find the given filename when it is executed in the root directory.

Comment: "Make sure all the data you read in your test module is relative to the location of setup.py directory." This fixes the problem when running "python setup.py test". However, when I run the tests in the test folder, they now fail. Is there a way to build the test so that it isn't sensitive to which directory I'm in when I execute pytest? I think that would be preferred.

Comment: try except block doesn't look bad to me, I am glad the answer helped.